# Alternative for Get-VICredentialStoreItem in Powershell 7.1

Tags: powershell, powercli

On Powershell 5.1, I use this command

```
New-VICredentialStoreItem -Host 10.1.1.2 -User "vsphere_admin" -Password 'PLAIN_PASSWORD' -File c:\cred.xml
```

to create a credential file which looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<viCredentials>
<version>2.0</version>
-<passwordEntry>
<host>10.1.1.2</host>
<username>vsphere_admin</username>
<password>AQA.....OCOWcDLY=</password>
</passwordEntry>
</viCredentials>
```

Then I am able to use that with the following powercli commands

```
$Credentials = Get-VICredentialStoreItem -Host $vcenter_server -File c:\pwd.xml
Connect-VIServer $vcenter_server -User $Credentials.User -Password $Credentials.Password
```

That is fine, but `Get-VICredentialStoreItem` is not valid in powershell 7. I see Microsoft [SecretManagement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/secretmanagement-and-secretstore-are-generally-available/), but don't know if that fits my need. Any thought on that?

Answer (score 1):

## Updated Answer

> I get this error on powershell 7 `Cmdlet Get-VICredentialStoreItem is not supported on PowerShell Core.` If there is a way to fix that then it will be good.

There is no way to get `Get-VICredentialStoreItem` working on PowerShell Core (PS 6.0+). The reason is that PowerShell Core is cross-platform and [the encryption API is Windows-only](https://youtu.be/Aig8_3eTF8o?t=1254) (YouTube).

You can also see a hint of this in the built-in help:

```
Get-Help Get-VICredentialStoreItem -Full

    NOTES

    This cmdlet is not supported on the Core edition of PowerShell.
```

On Windows, you can use *-VICredentialStoreItem in PowerShell 5.1.

In your crosspost, I noticed you were using *nix. So, you must use an alternative like SecretStore.

---

> the problem is whenever I use Get-Secret it asks for the vault password. Is there any way to store the secret and use that without ask?

Remember that:

> [SecretStore] can be configured to require a password to unlock the store, or operate without a password. The no-password option still encrypts secrets on file and in memory. But the key for decryption is stored on file in the current user location, and is less secure.

You can use this updated workflow which includes `Set-SecretStoreConfiguration`.

```
# Install SecretManagement and SecretStore from the PowerShell Gallery. 
Install-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretManagement, Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore

# Set no password for the vault. 
Set-SecretStoreConfiguration -Scope CurrentUser -Authentication None -Interaction None -Confirm:$false 
# Enter current password. 

# Register a vault. 
Register-SecretVault -Name SecretStore -ModuleName Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore -DefaultVault

# Add secrets to vault. 
Set-Secret -Name Host -Secret "10.1.1.2"
# No password prompt now. 
Set-Secret -Name User -Secret "vsphere_admin"
Set-Secret -Name Password -Secret "PLAIN_PASSWORD"

# Use secrets. 
# Connect-VIServer $vcenter_server -User (Get-Secret -Name User -AsPlainText) -Password (Get-Secret -Name Password -AsPlainText)
"Connect-VIServer $vcenter_server -User $(Get-Secret -Name User -AsPlainText) -Password $(Get-Secret -Name Password -AsPlainText)"
# Extra line to help with copying from Stack Overflow.
```

Then you can try launching a new shell. From there, you should be able to access secrets without being prompted for a password.

This solution is similar to your crosspost. There you forgot to include `-Authentication None` for `Set-SecretStoreConfiguration`.

### Undo configuration changes.

```
Get-SecretStoreConfiguration

          Scope Authentication PasswordTimeout Interaction
          ----- -------------- --------------- -----------
    CurrentUser           None             900        None

Set-SecretStoreConfiguration -Scope CurrentUser -Authentication Password -Interaction Prompt 

    Confirm
    Are you sure you want to perform this action?
    Performing the operation "Changes local store configuration" on target
    "SecretStore module local store".
    [Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help
    (default is "Y"):y
    A password is now required for the local store configuration.
    To complete the change please provide new password.
    Enter password:
    ********
    Enter password again for verification:
    ********

Get-SecretStoreConfiguration

    Vault Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore requires a password.
    Enter password:
    ********

          Scope Authentication PasswordTimeout Interaction
          ----- -------------- --------------- -----------
    CurrentUser       Password             900      Prompt
```

### References

- [Solved: "VICredentialStoreItem" Cmdlets don't support Powe... - VMware Technology Network VMTN](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-PowerCLI-Discussions/quot-VICredentialStoreItem-quot-Cmdlets-don-t-support-PowerShell/m-p/1861166)

## Original Answer

```
New-VICredentialStoreItem -Host 10.1.1.2 -User "vsphere_admin" -Password 'PLAIN_PASSWORD' -File c:\cred.xml
$Credentials = Get-VICredentialStoreItem -Host $vcenter_server -File c:\pwd.xml
```

You are referencing two different files: `cred.xml` and `pwd.xml`

---

Remember that everything is an object in PowerShell.

In your example, [Connect-VIServer](https://developer.vmware.com/docs/powercli/latest/vmware.vimautomation.core/commands/connect-viserver/#Default)'s `-User` and `-Password` parameters are expecting strings.

And you are [providing strings](https://developer.vmware.com/docs/powercli/latest/vmware.vimautomation.core/structures/vmware.vimautomation.vicore.types.v1.vicredentialstoreitem/): `$Credentials.User` and `$Credentials.Password`

So, a substitute will need to provide strings.

---

### SecretManagement and SecretStore

PowerShell has a new set of modules for managing secrets.

- [SecretManagement and SecretStore are Generally Available | PowerShell Team](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/secretmanagement-and-secretstore-are-generally-available/)

The purpose of secret management is to provide a central and secure location for secrets. Then you can replace a password written in a script with a reference to the secret manager. This allows you to update a password in one place but affect every script. It also allows you to share scripts because sensitive information is only referenced and not shown.

In PowerShell, **SecretManagement** is a common interface for multiple different vaults. This allows you to use one common set of cmdlets to access secrets but different back ends depending on your needs.

**SecretStore** is a usable demonstration vault provided by the PowerShell Team. SecretStore is only one type of vault. And there are other *extension vaults* available. For example, HashiCorp Vault or KeePass.

Because SecretManagement is only an interface and not a complete solution, it is important to carefully select a vault which is appropriate for your needs. Consider the following:

- Can I recover my vault after a system failure?
- Will my vault scale with my deployment?
- Is my vault for personal use?
- Will the secrets be shared between multiple users?

Remember that if you decide to switch vaults, you will have to use the SecretManagement cmdlets to transfer secrets between the vaults. This could be complicated and time-consuming.

With respect to VMware's credential store, does anyone else share that store with you? Are there any scripts which depend on it? While the underlying objects are strings, there might be issues with wholesale switching to a new secret manager.

We have both linked to the general availability announcement from the PowerShell Team. That post details the features and limitations of SecretManagement and SecretStore. And there is no substitute for reading that post and considering your needs.

---

### SecretManagement and SecretStore Example

Here is a simple example using SecretManagement and SecretStore.

```
# Install SecretManagement and SecretStore from the PowerShell Gallery. 
Install-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretManagement, Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore

# Set up a vault. 
Register-SecretVault -Name SecretStore -ModuleName Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore -DefaultVault

# Add secrets to vault. 
Set-Secret -Name Host -Secret "10.1.1.2"
# You will be prompted to enter a password for the new vault. 
Set-Secret -Name User -Secret "vsphere_admin"
Set-Secret -Name Password -Secret "PLAIN_PASSWORD"

# Use secrets. 
# Connect-VIServer $vcenter_server -User (Get-Secret -Name User -AsPlainText) -Password (Get-Secret -Name Password -AsPlainText)
"Connect-VIServer $vcenter_server -User $(Get-Secret -Name User -AsPlainText) -Password $(Get-Secret -Name Password -AsPlainText)"
# Extra line to help with copying from Stack Overflow.
```

#### Command History

SecretManagement cmdlets do not appear in the final [command history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/about/about_psreadline?view=powershell-5.1#command-history) on disc. But, it is possible to push the up arrow in PowerShell to view recent commands. This would expose your secrets. And there might be other types of PowerShell logging in use.

- [Get-History (Microsoft.PowerShell.Core) - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-history?view=powershell-7.1)
- [about_Logging - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logging)
- [Auditing and Reporting on JEA - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/jea/audit-and-report?view=powershell-7.1#session-transcripts)

If you want to hide your typed secrets from more types of logging, you can enter a secure string.

```
# Use Read-Host -AsSecureString.
Set-Secret -Name LoggingExample -SecureStringSecret (Read-Host "Enter a secret for LoggingExample. " -AsSecureString)
# Show plaintext. 
Get-Secret -Name LoggingExample -AsPlainText
```

#### Remove secrets.

In the following sections, I undo the installation.

```
Get-SecretInfo

    Name     Type   VaultName
    ----     ----   ---------
    Host     String SecretStore
    Password String SecretStore
    User     String SecretStore

Get-SecretInfo | Remove-Secret

    Vault SecretStore requires a password.
    Enter password:
    ********

Get-SecretInfo
# Nothing is displayed.
```

#### Remove vault.

```
Get-SecretVault

    Name        ModuleName                       IsDefaultVault
    ----        ----------                       --------------
    SecretStore Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore True

Get-SecretVault | Unregister-SecretVault
Get-SecretVault
# Nothing.
```

#### Remove modules.

```
# Close and reopen PowerShell. 
Get-InstalledModule | Format-Table -AutoSize

    Version Name                                  Repository Description
    ------- ----                                  ---------- -----------
    1.0.0   Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretManagement PSGallery  This module provides …
    1.0.0   Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore      PSGallery  This PowerShell modul…

Uninstall-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore
Uninstall-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretManagement
Get-InstalledModule | Format-Table -AutoSize
# Nothing.
```

---

### PowerCLI Compatibility

> `Get-VICredentialStoreItem` is not valid in powershell 7.

It is not clear why you say this.

Also, it is not clear why replacing `Get-VICredentialStoreItem` would help because I assume `Connect-VIServer` won't work in the same environment.

VMware states [PowerCLI is compatible](https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/1f965bde-564c-4593-a63c-b29d2ea3d401/d91027aa-e3ef-4467-a573-d76f66bdb6ac/powercli123-compat-matrix.html) with PowerShell 7.

> Supported PowerShell Versions
>
> VMware PowerCLI 12.3.0 is compatible with the following PowerShell versions:
>
> - Windows PowerShell 5.1
> - PowerShell 7

If you mean to say that PowerCLI is not compatible with PowerShell 7.1 then is there an error message?

Have you reported a bug to VMware? There might be a [compatibility problem](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13138) with the underlying module which VMware can address.

You have not stated why you are using PowerShell 7.1.

If PowerCLI is only supported in earlier versions of PowerShell then I suggest using the compatible version. There have only been a few obscure changes between PowerShell 7.0 and 7.1.

- [What's New in PowerShell 7.1 - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-powershell-71?view=powershell-7.1)
- [PowerShell/7.1.md at master · PowerShell/PowerShell · GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/CHANGELOG/7.1.md)

If you want production support from Microsoft, PowerShell 7.0 is supported until December 3, 2022 and PowerShell 5.1 is still supported as part of Windows 10.

- [PowerShell Core Support Lifecycle - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/powershell-support-lifecycle?view=powershell-7.1#powershell-releases-end-of-life)

---

### References

- [Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretManagement Module - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.secretmanagement/?view=ps-modules)
- [Secret Management, February 2021 | CNCF Radars](https://radar.cncf.io/2021-02-secrets-management)

Comment: I get this error on powershell 7 `Cmdlet Get-VICredentialStoreItem is not supported on PowerShell Core.` If there is a way to fix that then it will be good.

Comment: OK I setup the vault and it seems to be working. However, the problem is whenever I use `Connect-VIServer $vcenter_server -User (Get-Secret -Name User -AsPlainText) -Password (Get-Secret -Name Password -AsPlainText)`, it asks for the vault password. Is there any way to store the secret and use that without ask?

Comment: I updated my answer to address your questions.